# Change execution concurrency of Airflow DAG

Tags: python, concurrency, airflow

I would like to change the `dag_concurrency` parameter of a specific Airflow DAG. It seems there is a global `dag_concurrency` parameter in `airflow.cfg` but is it possible to set different values for different DAGs?

I have tried to add a concurrency parameter in my DAG code in the `SSHExecuteOperator` task but the concurrency value still shows the standard parameter (16) in the DAG details.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_execute_operator import SSHExecuteOperator

default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': datetime.now(),
  'email': ['exceptions@airflow.com'],
  'email_on_failure': True,
  'retries': 0
}

#server must be changed to point to the correct environment
sshHookEtl = SSHHook(conn_id='SSH__airflow@myserver')

with DAG(
  'ed_data_quality_20min-v1.6.6',
  default_args=default_args,
  schedule_interval="0,20,40 * * * *",
  dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=24)) as dag:
  (
    dag
    >> SSHExecuteOperator(
          task_id='run_remote_ed_data_quality_20min',
          bash_command='bash /opt/scripts/shell/EXEC_ED_DATA_QUALITY_20MIN.sh ',
          ssh_hook=sshHookEtl,
          retries=0,
          concurrency=1,
          dag=dag)
  )
```

[Here is the DAG details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBsg.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I was not adding the concurrency parameter in the right place. It should be added as an attribute of the `DAG` object directly and not in the task `SSHExecuteOperator`. Here is the new code:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_execute_operator import SSHExecuteOperator

default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': datetime.now(),
  'email': ['exceptions@airflow.com'],
  'email_on_failure': True,
  'retries': 0
}

#server must be changed to point to the correct environment
sshHookEtl = SSHHook(conn_id='SSH__airflow@myserver')

with DAG(
  'ed_data_quality_20min-v1.6.6',
  default_args=default_args,
  schedule_interval="0,20,40 * * * *",
  dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=24),
  concurrency=1) as dag:
  (
    dag
    >> SSHExecuteOperator(
          task_id='run_remote_ed_data_quality_20min',
          bash_command='bash /opt/scripts/shell/EXEC_ED_DATA_QUALITY_20MIN.sh ',
          ssh_hook=sshHookEtl,
          retries=0,
          dag=dag)
  )
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to spot the difference between your answer and question sample. Consider excepting just the changed lines and EXPLAIN the change.

Answer (score 1):

Okay…
You can [just set](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.DAG) the `concurrency` on the `DAG` object.
There's also a `task_concurrency` on the `BaseOperator` object. There is no `concurrency` param nor field on the `SSHExectorOperator` or `BaseOperator` task.